# IndexError: list index out of range with csv

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file that contains multiple columns
when I run this code in the first column, will run fine,
but when I run it in another column, will display this error
`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
array_of_ids = []
with open('reactions/by_ids.csv','r',newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)

  for row in reader:
    array_of_ids.append(row[2])
```

so, `row[0]` works, `row[2]` does not work!!

Comment: The row doesn't have 3 elements then. Have you inspected row to see what it holds?

Comment: Ohh, that's right ... when I wrote to this file `row[2]`, that makes one column.
thanks, man, you helped me!

Comment: Always make sure you're checking the data associated with the error. 90% of the time, that will lead you to the right solution.

Comment: Good advice, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at your CSV file in a file editor and ensure that each line contains at least 3 entries. A common problem is when your CSV file contains a blank link e.g. the last line.

You could always add `if len(row) == 3:` before doing your append, this would then have the effect of skipping over any lines that are not correctly formated, for example:

```
import csv

array_of_ids = []

with open('reactions/by_ids.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 3:
            array_of_ids.append(row[2])
```